# Unsupported URL for image layer mapbox iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am trying to learn [mapbox maps iOS](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.0.0-rc.9/) but am struggling with inserting an image layer.

The image is however, failing to load, throwing the error:

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"`

The docs for for this structure are [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.0.0-rc.9/Protocols/Layer.html)

Please help!!!

`ViewController.swift:`

```
mapView.mapboxMap.onNext(.mapLoaded) { _ in
    self.addImageLayer()
}
```

```
internal func addImageLayer() {
    var sourceId = "planet-source"
    let style = mapView.mapboxMap.style

    // Create an `ImageSource`. This will manage the image displayed in the `RasterLayer` as well
    // as the location of that image on the map.
    var imageSource = ImageSource()

    // Set the `coordinates` property to an array of longitude, latitude pairs.
    imageSource.coordinates = [
        [-80.425, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 37.936],
        [-80.425, 37.936]
    ]

    // Get the file path for the first radar image, then set the `url` for the `ImageSource` to that path.
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "planet", ofType: "svg")!
    imageSource.url = path

    // Create a `RasterLayer` that will display the images from the `ImageSource`
    var imageLayer = Layer(id: "planet-layer")
    imageLayer.source = sourceId

    do {
        try style.addSource(imageSource, id: sourceId)
        try style.addLayer(imageLayer)

    } catch {
        print("Failed to add the source or layer to style. Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: The same error, I started thinking about using mapbox v6 instead of v10. Have you managed to resolve this error?